# Spotfire: My SQL Queries are not running in Spotfire while it runs in SQL Server Management Studio?

Tags: sql-server, spotfire

Shows the following error-

> External error:
>   Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'Use'.
>   Incorrect syntax near ')'.

Submitted query:

```
Use VPDC
exec vpdc.pa.spMaybeDrop #AllSOText
SELECT DISTINCT dt.UnitID, dt.MainPlatform, dt.SBU, dt.country,dt.HighestContract, pa.fnStripLeadingZeroes(dSO.ServiceOrderNumber) ServiceOrderNumber, dso.StatusOrderNumber, dso.StatusOrderNumberText, ServiceOrderText, ServiceOrderLongText, Cast(BasicStart as date) BasicStart, orderType

into #AllSOText
from aa.vwSAPServiceOrders_OneLinePerServiceOrder dSO
inner join aa.vwTurbines dt on dt.UnitId = dso.UnitId
```

While it works fine in SQL Server Management Studio.

Answer (score 1):

Remove the "Use VPDC". This is specific to management studio to change context to a database. In client apps this is specified in the connection string or you can write the script with database context, as below:

```
exec vpdc.pa.spMaybeDrop #AllSOText

SELECT DISTINCT dt.UnitID, dt.MainPlatform, dt.SBU, dt.country,dt.HighestContract, pa.fnStripLeadingZeroes(dSO.ServiceOrderNumber) ServiceOrderNumber, dso.StatusOrderNumber, dso.StatusOrderNumberText, ServiceOrderText, ServiceOrderLongText, Cast(BasicStart as date) BasicStart, orderType
into #AllSOText
from vpdc.aa.vwSAPServiceOrders_OneLinePerServiceOrder dSO
inner join vpdc.aa.vwTurbines dt on dt.UnitId = dso.UnitId
```